# postback datetime is defaulted - generic postback value solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a property in my model that holds the DateTime:

```
[Required, Display(Name = "Due Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
```

When I bind it to the view, I do this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DueDate)
```

When I postback, the value is set to the default value of DateTime.Min. I see the value being set in the DOM/HTML.

So here is the question: how can I postback and make the value bind to the model but also making sure it works for all possible cultures?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about just using a nullable? If it has no value, it will indicate that by being null. The problem with a straight DateTime is that it has to be set to *something*, so it should only be used when a value is required from the user or will otherwise always be set with something meaningful.

Comment: I agree.  I always use nullables on dates and if it's required I mark it with `Required`.  This keeps the pesky 01/01/0001 from showing up which explodes on SQL Server because it only allows dates back to 1753.